# Preset numeric keypad in iPhone for textbox in c#

Tags: iphone, keyboard

Hi I want to preset numeric keypad for input textbox in my web application for mobile pages to view in iPhone.

Comment: needs coding from iPhone side not from c# side, I think

Comment: Webapp and C# don't really go together...

Comment: +1 to counter the negative. I'm not sure what troll gave you a minus on a legitimate question that google pulled up and that has helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean HTML/CSS/JS by 'my web application'...

Just set the input's type to `number`.

```
<input type="number" value="0" placeholder="Only numbers here!" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..
you are right that by setting type="number" we can preset numeric keypad but when we use it with runat=server attribute for textbox its not accepting type=number.

Comment: I found the solution. By using type=numer we can preset numeric keypad but it was not working with runat=server attribute.
For that i have changed the type of textbox to number after loading the page to client side with javascript and it works.